# I want to know: what is the principle that causes this phenomenon?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, fractals, soft-matter

The effect of fractal fingering can be observed if a droplet of an ink-alcohol mixture is deposited onto diluted acrylic paint. How are the geometry and dynamics of the fingers influenced by relevant parameters?

[image]

Comment: You need to be morce specific. What are your "relevant parameters" ?

Comment: I don't know. I just started college this year, and my teacher asked me to research the subject. Could you please tell me where I should start?

Comment: Welcome @aoxue.  This is a [2023 International Young Physicists Tournament question](https://www.iypt.org/problems/problems-for-the-36th-iypt-2023/). As this American Physical Society [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DguNgm9tDFU) notes, formation of such "dendrites" (branched fingers) is still not perfectly understood, so there is lots for you to explore. Think about what you can vary and see what appends, e.g. ink/alcohol ratios, temperature, thickness of layers, types of ink/paint/alcohol, .... "Take chances, make mistakes, get messy!"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As it's a tournament question I voted to close under the homework-type question policy.

Comment: All right,thank you everyone.